Is there a Bible analogy where God took over an individual's thinking to save his life?
In a recent news event, the former president of the USA miraculously turned his head and survived an assassination by an inch. Is God capable of controlling our bodies through putting thoughts in our heads? For example in the case of Trump, he thought to turn right and look at the statistics billboard which consequently made the bullet miss by an inch which saved his life. The most amazing fact is the timing to look at the billboard and the shot being fired coincided, which shows there is a divine intervention to save his life because he could have easily thought to look at the supporters in front which would have ended badly.
Most people who have been interviewed on the media say it was divine intervention that saved Trump, is this true and is there a Bible analogy where God saved someone by changing their thoughts?

Is trump the beast that was wounded and recovered in the book of revelation?

Unlikely. The head wound in Revelation was thought to have been fatal, so much more serious than Trump's wound. Also, the wounded figure in Revelation may be an individual but might also be an organization or kingdom.

@PaulChernoch, it was a deadly wound because he survived by an inch

@PaulChernoch, define a deadly wound, a wound that is inflicted as a result of an event that would have claimed someone's life

Does "is this true" refer to "most people say" or to "it was divine intervention"? Either way, questions of truth are not suitable for this site.

"The most amazing fact is the timing to look at the billboard and the shot being fired coincided, which shows there is a divine intervention..."  False.  Not every coincidence of events is due to Divine intervention.

God caused Balaam's donkey to halt in Numbers 22, saving the foolish prophet from dying at the hand of an angel.

well answered, God directly caused the donkey to think and gave it an extra ability to speak. Upvoted and Accepted for the angel had his orders and would have slayed Balaam.

A donkey is not an individual therfore it is not an example of God taking over an idividual's thinking.

The attempt at an analogy with a recent failed assassination attempt is not a good one. Consider all other famous people who were assassinated. And bear in mind that a future assassination attempt on the person mentioned might succeed. What will his supporters say then? "Oh, he's a martyr!" and their adoration of him will know no bounds.
Consider also how the Bible points out this simple fact of life:

"The race is not to the swift, nor the battle to the strong, neither
yet bread to the wise, nor yet riches to men of understanding, nor yet
favour to men of skill; but time and chance happeneth to them all."
Ecclesiastes 9:11 A.V.

Consider also how Satan is said to influence the thoughts and actions of some. When Judas Iscariot thought to influence events according to what he thought they should be, Satan began to influence him, to the point that he "entered into" Judas to ensure Judas did what Satan wanted done, to betray Jesus and thus get the Son of God crucified. John 13:18, 26-27  And that betrayer committed suicide shortly after. Jesus said it would have been better for that man had he never been born.
Consider further how, when an angel of the Lord caused Balaam's donkey to act and then to speak to the prophet in rebuke, that was not God "taking over an individual's thinking to save him" - an animal is not "an individual", and just see the final end of Balaam. He was not saved at all.
God is said to "speak" to individuals, to inform them, to advise them, to save them. That would apply to the example of God giving a dream to Abimelech, which the king knew to be a warning from God, and he chose to act on that warning. His mind was not controlled by God in order to be saved. He was warned and acted wisely on that warning.
But nowhere does he "take over" their thinking. And there are other times when God speaks directly to individuals to tell them that they are doomed, because they refuse to "allow" God's thoughts and instructions to affect their thinking.
This answer is a simple "No", unless and until such times as another answer gives an example of what is being asked for.

So you believe his own hand saved him from the plans of the devil? I thought only God could do that.

God can influence human thoughts and guiding actions, often through the Holy Spirit's work. However, this influence respects human free will, allowing individuals to choose how they respond to God’s promptings. God’s power to guide and inspire does not negate personal responsibility for one's thoughts and actions.
Therefore, whether God is capable of controlling our bodies by putting thoughts in our heads is rooted in the understanding of God's omnipotence, human free will, and the role of the Holy Spirit.
God's Omnipotence
Christians believe that God is all-powerful and has the capability to do anything that aligns with His nature. This includes the ability to influence human thoughts and actions. The Bible suggests that God can place thoughts in a person's mind to guide them, as seen in examples like God giving Nebuchadnezzar a troubling dream (Daniel 2:1) or guiding the hearts of kings (Proverbs 21:1).
Human Free Will and Responsibility
Despite God's ability to influence thoughts, Christianity teaches that humans have free will and moral responsibility. God respects the freedom He has given people to choose their actions. While God can guide, prompt, or persuade, He does not usually override free will by completely controlling a person’s thoughts or actions. Instead, He may provide direction or conviction, allowing individuals to respond according to their will.
The Role of the Holy Spirit
In Christian belief, the Holy Spirit plays a key role in influencing thoughts. The Spirit can prompt believers, give them wisdom, convict them of sin, and bring God's truth to mind (John 14:26; John 16:8). These influences are often subtle and can manifest as thoughts, inner impressions, or feelings guiding people toward God's will. However, believers are still responsible for responding to the Holy Spirit’s promptings.
Biblical Examples
There are instances in the Bible where God appears to influence people’s thoughts for His purposes. For example, God hardened Pharaoh’s heart in Exodus (Exodus 9:12), and He put it in Nehemiah’s heart to rebuild Jerusalem’s wall (Nehemiah 2:12). In the New Testament, God opened Lydia's heart to respond to Paul’s message (Acts 16:14). These instances suggest that while God can influence thoughts, He typically does so in ways that encourage cooperation rather than coercion.
God’s Influence Without Coercion
The idea is that God can put thoughts in people’s minds as part of His guidance or prompting, but He does not forcefully control their minds against their will. He may reveal truths, bring Scripture to memory, or provide insight, but people have the freedom to accept or reject these influences.

Hello and welcome to the site. While we can't know for sure, this post does seem very similar to what ChatGPT and other AIs would produce. If that is the case, you should know that posting ChatGPT answers here is not allowed - answers are expected to be the creation of the human posting them, and we also expect answers to have supporting evidence in the form of quotes and references to other Christian publications. Please keep that in mind as you continue posting. And welcome!

Gen 20:3-6

God came to Abimelech in a dream by night, and said to him, Behold,
thou art but a dead man, for the woman which thou hast taken; for she
is a man's wife.  But Abimelech had not come near her: and he said,
Lord, wilt thou slay also a righteous nation?  Said he not unto me,
She is my sister? and she, even she herself said, He is my brother: in
the integrity of my heart and innocency of my hands have I done this. 
And God said unto him in a dream, Yea, I know that thou didst this in
the integrity of thy heart; for I also withheld thee from sinning
against me: therefore suffered I thee not to touch her.

